# His school tardiness is improved or his school tardy has improved since last meeting

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

His school tardiness is improved or his school tardy has improved since last meeting

Comment: should those both be "tardiness" (as I understood them), or do you actually mean "tardy" there?

Answer (score 1):

Both could be correct.

> His school tardniess is improved.

This means that his measured level of tardiness right now is better than it was at some time in the past. Not normally encountered in AmEng, but perhaps in BrEng.

> His school tardiness has improved.

This means that his tardiness record has improved when compared to some previous time. More common in AmEng.

Comment: One assumes the original question should be;
"His school tardiness is improved or his school tardiness has improved"

As Davo suggests, both are correct. However, it should be pointed out that the question as posted says 
"His school tardy has improved" 
which is not correct but I guess that may have been a typing error.

Also worth mentioning "His school tardiness is improved" is an older form and less commonly used in modern day British English.

Comment: is there a typo in the first example? ([tardniess](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=tardniess)?)